# Change border shape of button

Tags: html, css

[image]

1)I want to change "submit" button border in circle shape as below image as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/fanbook)

[image]

```
.submit1 {
    background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: Change the border radious i.e : border-radius: 10px; you ill get the result.
and for this question answer is available already.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but rounded corners are just about the easiest things to do in CSS. You could have put more time into research.

Comment: By the way, you could right click an element you see in any webpage and click Inspect Element to find out what are the styles applied. This way, you can instantly get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `border-radius` to round shape.

```
.submit1 {
        background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: medium none;
        border-radius:8px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 8px;
        min-width: 140px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add border-radius as required

```css
.submit1 {
    background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<button class="submit1">
  Upload Picture
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

You just want to add `border-radius: 50px;`

```
.submit1 {
    background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
<button class="submit1">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put a container div to your button,

```
<div style="border:5px solid gray;background-color:gray;max-width: 140px;">
  <input type="button" class="submit1" value="submit" />
</div>
```

css

```
.submit1 {
    background: #ff7704 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this, and use correct image, i just put sample image from online

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.submit1 {
    background-color: #ff7704;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
 padding-right:70px;
    min-width: 140px;
 background-image:url('http://troncell.com/images/hdsp/ht-icon-1.png');
 background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
</style>
<body>
<button class="submit1">Upload Picture</button>
</body>
</html>
```